# How to setup or find an impedance across the capacitor

Tags: measure

I have a 1.8V circuitry with two parallel capacitors and please let me know how can I setup or find out the impedance across the capacitor C420.

[image]

Comment: Is there anything else connected to VCC1V8? Do you have a simulator to simulate it or do you want to measure it on your board?

Comment: Welcome! At what frequency?

Comment: Forget about the impedance; what are you trying to establish more realistically?

Answer (score 3):

For this specific case, in which the capacitors are connected to a DC source, their impedance is esentially infinite. It is well known that capacitors act as an open circuit when conected to a DC source. Basically, the electrons try to accumulate on one of the elctrodes but the dielectric gap prevents any significant current from flowing, thus, we consider the capacitors to behave as an open circuit.

We can model the impedance of the capacitor by the following formula (that you may have seen):

[image: formula]

Then, since DC sources are essentially a source with 0Hz you can see that the value of Xc, according to the equation, aproaches infinity.